# Sequelize: use field created in sequelize.literal in where clause

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize .literal function to create an aggragated field, which was not achievable in other ways. Now I want to use sequelize's built-in "where" clause to filter by values on this new field.

```
DB_A.findAll({
attributes: {
  include: [
    [
      sequelize.literal(
        `(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM DB_B as DB_B WHERE DB_B.a_id = DB_A.id)`
      ),
      "b_count",
    ],
         
  ]} 
where:{ b_count:{[Op.gte]:10}}
 })
```

When I do this, I get "Unknown column 'DB_A.b_count' in 'where clause'". I've also tried:

```
where:{[sequelize.literal("b_count")]:...}
```

Which works with the order property from sequelize, but not here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out. You need to use "having" instead of "where", as it would be the way to do with regular MySQL. For some reason `Sequelize.having` is not on the DOCS/API, and I already opened an issue at the git repo.

The above code would then be:

```
DB_A.findAll({
attributes: {
  include: [
    [
      sequelize.literal(
        `(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM DB_B as DB_B WHERE DB_B.a_id = DB_A.id)`
      ),
      "b_count",
    ],
         
  ]} 
having:{ ["b_count"]:{[Op.gte]:10}}
 })
```

Comment: still not working with postgress